# How can you install Mono 3.x on earlier versions of Ubuntu (12.x)?

Tags: mono

We are developing a video game we intend to release on Linux. It requires the use of the Mono 3.x runtime. However the command `apt-get install mono-complete` only installs Mono 2.10.

How can we get Mono 3.x on a Ubuntu 12.x OS in a way that is as user-friendly as possible?

Comment: Huh? No the end-user will need Mono 3.x to play the game. We need to install it for the user as part of installing the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Mono 3 in Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 with [**ppa:v-kukol/mono-3**](https://launchpad.net/~v-kukol/+archive/ubuntu/mono-3) repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-kukol/mono-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this generally an acceptable thing to run for the end-user to get the game working? Eg could we throw this into a one-time bash script.